# Create a multiple choice question with buttons and a text question using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am learning javascript and I am just a novice. I am trying to create two simple questions. The first one is a multiple choice with buttons and the second one is just a text question. Here is my `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Trivia!</title>

        <script>

            function displayAnswer1() {
                if (document.getElementById('option-11').checked) {
                  document.getElementById('block-11').style.border = '3px solid red'
                  document.getElementById('result-11').style.background = 'red'
                  document.getElementById('result-11').innerHTML = 'Incorrect!!'
                }
                if (document.getElementById('option-12').checked) {
                  document.getElementById('block-12').style.border = '3px solid red'
                  document.getElementById('result-12').style.background = 'red'
                  document.getElementById('result-12').innerHTML = 'Incorrect!'
                  showCorrectAnswer4()
                }
                if (document.getElementById('option-13').checked) {
                  document.getElementById('block-13').style.border = '3px solid red'
                  document.getElementById('result-13').style.background = 'red'
                  document.getElementById('result-13').innerHTML = 'Incorrect!'
                  showCorrectAnswer4()
                }
                if (document.getElementById('option-14').checked) {
                  document.getElementById('block-14').style.border = '3px solid limegreen'
                  document.getElementById('result-14').style.background = 'limegreen'
                  document.getElementById('result-14').innerHTML = 'Correct!!'
                  showCorrectAnswer4()
                }
             }
             
             function showCorrectAnswer4() {
                let showAnswer4 = document.createElement('p')
                showAnswer1.innerHTML = 'Show Corrent Answer'
                showAnswer1.style.position = 'relative'
                showAnswer1.style.top = '-180px'
                showAnswer1.style.fontSize = '1.75rem'
                document.getElementById('showanswer4').appendChild(showAnswer4)
                showAnswer1.addEventListener('click', () => {
                  document.getElementById('block-14').style.border = '3px solid limegreen'
                  document.getElementById('result-14').style.background = 'limegreen'
                  document.getElementById('result-14').innerHTML = 'Correct!'
                  document.getElementById('showanswer4').removeChild(showAnswer4)
                })
              }
              
              function myfun(){
                var v1=document.getElementById('form').elements[0].value;

                 console.log('came',v1,)
        
                
                if(v1=="Blue"){
                        v1.style.color='green';
                        v1.innerHTML = 'Correct!'
                }
                        
                        


                 else {
                  v1.style.color='red';
                        v1.innerHTML = 'Incorrect!'
                }
        
            }

        </script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Trivia!</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="container">

            <div class="section">
                <h2>Part 1: Multiple Choice </h2>
                <hr>

                <h3>What is my first name?</h3>
                <form method='GET'>
                    <span id='block-11' style='padding: 10px;'>
                        <label for='option-11' style=' padding: 5px; font-size: 2.5rem;'>
                          <input type='submit' value='Zahra' id='option-11' style='transform: scale(1.6); margin-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle; margin-top: -2px;' onclick="displayAnswer1()"/>
                          </label>
                        <span id='result-11'></span>
                    </span>
                    <span id='block-12' style='padding: 10px;'>
                        <label for='option-12' style=' padding: 5px; font-size: 2.5rem;'>
                          <input type='submit' value='Melika' id='option-12' style='transform: scale(1.6); margin-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle; margin-top: -2px;' onclick="displayAnswer1()"/>
                          </label>
                        <span id='result-12'></span>
                    </span>
                    <span id='block-12' style='padding: 10px;'>
                        <label for='option-13' style=' padding: 5px; font-size: 2.5rem;'>
                          <input type='submit'  value='Aysa' id='option-13' style='transform: scale(1.6); margin-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle; margin-top: -2px;' onclick="displayAnswer1()"/>
                          </label>
                        <span id='result-13'></span>
                    </span>
                    <span id='block-12' style='padding: 10px;'>
                        <label for='option-14' style=' padding: 5px; font-size: 2.5rem;'>
                          <input type='submit'  value='Aylin' id='option-14' style='transform: scale(1.6); margin-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle; margin-top: -2px;' onclick="displayAnswer1()"/>
                          </label>
                        <span id='result-14'></span>
                    </span>
                 </form>
                

            </div>

            <div class="section">
                <h2>Part 2: Free Response</h2>
                <hr>

                <h3>What is my favorite color?</h3>
                    <form id="form">
                        <input type="text" name="q">
                        <input type="submit" value="Check Answer" onclick="myfun()">
                    </form>
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is my `style.css`:

```
body {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #212529;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
}

.container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.jumbotron {
    background-color: #477bff;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    padding: 2rem 1rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.section {
    padding: 0.5rem 2rem 1rem 2rem;
}

.section:hover {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    transition: color 2s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 48px;
}

button, input[type="submit"] {
    background-color: #d9edff;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    font-size: 0.95rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
    text-align: center;
    transition: color 0.15s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
    vertical-align: middle;
}


input[type="text"] {
    line-height: 1.8;
    width: 25%;
}

input[type="text"]:hover {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    transition: color 2s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out;
}
```

Something that I want for multiple choices question is when the user clicks on the correct answer the color of the button changes in green and a message like **Correct!** be shown under the question and if the user chose the wrong button its color changes into the red with an **Incorrect** message.
And for the next question if the user writes the correct answer I want to change the color of the text into green and show a **Correct** message to the user.

My first problem is that why after clicking on the correct or wrong answer in the first question the color of the buttons does not change? and also why the text of `innerHTML` is not shown? I have the same problem with my second question that it does not show the message and does not change the color of the text which has been written in the `input`.
[CodePen link](https://codepen.io/AylinNaebZadeh/pen/GREWdBZ)
I will be really grateful for your help or advice.

Comment: Can you add a codepen or something similar? Might be easier for people to help you if they can see the code in action.

Comment: I have added a link just now. Does the link work correctly?@displacedtexan

Comment: the link works but clicking on the buttons returns an error from codepen. You might have better luck *not* using a form element because it's probably what's trying to reload the page. You don't need it in this case. Sorry I can't be more help.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. @displacedtexan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I think I have achieved what you were asking.
Sandbox for reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-kate-4kl3z?file=/index.html

Couple times you were targeting divs with ids that did not exist, so just make sure to double check naming and such. And like @displacedtexan stated the form is most likely not needed, I left it there and just changed the `input` types to `button` instead of `submit` . Feel free to comment if more help is needed.

Comment: Actually, I want to use the `CSS` codes and that's why I used the `input` tag. And the other thing that I wanted is to change the background color of my buttons after clicking on the wrong or the correct answer. And also for my text `input` question how can I change the color of the text(if it was correct it becomes green and if it was wrong it becomes red)?Thanks.

Comment: I believe my sandbox link has the functionality for the 2nd question with changing the text colour depending if correct or incorrect.

Comment: I have checked it both on my system and in your link, but it did not change.@Lowgy

Comment: Hmmm thats weird. Not sure why it would not be working. When I log out of my sandbox, I am still able to view and it works fine.

Comment: I run it again and it writes `<input type="text" name="q" style="color: red;"></input>
` in console but I do not know why I can not see the effect.

Comment: I found something. The colour of the answer does not change for the first time but when I write another thing in the `input` it works fine

Comment: Yeah the colour doesnt change till the button has been clicked i believe.

Comment: May you a bit explain why the `innerHTML` message is not rendered?

Comment: What to show what code you are referring to? I assume it involves the question one?

Comment: No, for the second question. In `myfun()` function I have used `innerHTML`.But I think it is not shown when I click on the button.

Comment: For `input` you would use `.value` instead of `.innerHTML`